# Buscar lista de objetos Json do localStorage por parte do nome de suas chaves

Tags: javascript, html5, json

sei que o localStorage dos navegadores armazena dados no formato de chave-valor, e que posso recuperar os objetos Json salvos alí através da chave. Agora o que eu preciso fazer é recuperar todos os registros cuja chave começam por "Deposito". Isto porque eu quero criar um gerador de sequência, para que cada chave de objeto depósito tenha acrescentado à ela um  número.

Por exemplo: Depósito01 {...
             Depósito02 {...
Uma vez recuperado todos os registros, eu iria extrair esses dois caracteres finais para descobrir qual foi o último depósito inserido, e incrementar em +1 no nome da chave do próximo depósito...

Também não sei como fazer isso, mas vou tentar. O que eu preciso primeiro mesmo é recuperar os objetos por parte do nome de suas chaves...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop:

```
localStorage.clear();

localStorage.Deposito1 = 'item 1';
localStorage.Deposito2 = 'item 2';
localStorage.Deposito3 = 'item 3';

for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length;) {
    console.log(localStorage[`Deposito${i++}`]);
}
```

Para pegar o último número é só usar:

```
localStorage[`Deposito${localStorage.length + 1}`] = 'item n';
```

Essa é uma forma simples porém, se na sua aplicação você possui outros dados salvos em localStorage pode haver algum erro, para isso tem que ser criado um array apenas com as chaves de depósito, e sempre deve atualizar ele quando houver alguma mudança no localStorage para outras ações não serem prejudicadas:

```
var deposito = [];

for(let element of Object.keys(localStorage)) {
    if(element.search('Deposito') == 0) {
        deposito.push(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso, eu não pensei que não precisaria de um loop, achei que teria algum método que pra gerar isso. Outra coisa que eu não sabi: o símbolo que representa "qualquer caractere que vier depois" no javascript, que no caso é o "$" então... Obrigado, ajudou bastante.